# Start JVM from Python without third party libraries?

Tags: java, python, class, jvm, subprocess

Is there a way to start the JVM (with a specified Java class to run and, perhaps, some arguments) from Python **without** third party libraries (e.g. Jython)? Maybe with Python's [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module?

I'm not concerned with calling methods on a Java class from Python, just starting a Java application.

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess module should work fine. Is there a specific problem you are having with using it?

Comment: I haven't used it before. Could you provide an example if possible?

Comment: @Mantis, there are examples at the link you posted in the question. There are a lot of ways to use subprocess, so any specific example won't be much use to you. You'll have to try it out with your use case and let us know any errors or problems you have or things you don't understand from the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module for this purpose.

I used [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to

> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output  = subprocess.check_output("java test")
>>> output
'hello world\r\n'
>>>
```

where `test.java` is a standard `hello world` example java file.

Alternatively you can use `check_call`

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_call('java test')
hello world
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is how to start a java application like any external app. you can use

```
>>> variables= {}
>>> execfile( "someFile.jar", variables )
```